# More concise SQL query involving MAX()

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, subquery, max

```
inventory
+------------------+-------------------+------------+
| DVD              | replacement_price |      stock |
+------------------+-------------------+------------+
| Pi               |              9.99 |        500 |
| Dune             |             29.99 |        100 |
| Heathers         |              4.99 |         20 |
| Jaws             |             19.99 |        500 |
| Mulholland_Drive |             39.99 |         50 |
| Waking_Life      |             29.99 |        200 |
+------------------+-------------------+------------+

rented
+-----------------+-----------+------------------+
| subscriber      | queue_nbr | DVD              |
+-----------------+-----------+------------------+
| Bob             |         1 | Mulholland_Drive |
| Bob             |         2 | Jaws             |
| Chey            |         1 | Pi               |
| Chey            |         2 | Heathers         |
| Jamie           |         2 | Mulholland_Drive |
| Jamie           |         4 | Dune             |
| Jamie           |         1 | Jaws             |
| Jamie           |         3 | Waking_Life      |
| Nora            |         4 | Jaws             |
| Nora            |         2 | Mulholland_Drive |
| Nora            |         3 | Dune             |
| Nora            |         1 | Waking_Life      |
+-----------------+-----------+------------------+
```

I want to return ONLY the subscriber(s) with the priciest movie queue (think Netflix DVD replacement costs if you lost all the movies you had out at a given time). I've used MAX() rather than TOP, LIMIT or ROWNUM because the query needs to be as db-independent as possible and must return multiple subscribers in the event of a tie. Using the tables above, the result should be

```
+---------+
| highest |
+---------+
| Jamie   |
| Nora    |
+---------+
```

After much searching and experimentation, I've come up with code that works, but it seems to my novice eyes bloated and inefficient, both in quantity of code and execution.

Would anyone mind refactoring and explaining your code?

My code:

```
SELECT z.subscriber highest
FROM 
(SELECT MAX(price) max_price
    FROM (
        SELECT subscriber_name subscriber, SUM(replacement_price) price
        FROM inventory i
        INNER JOIN rented r
        ON i.DVD = r.DVD
        GROUP BY subscriber
    ) x
) y
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT subscriber_name subscriber, SUM(replacement_price) price
    FROM inventory i
    INNER JOIN rented r
    ON i.DVD = r.DVD
    GROUP BY subscriber
) z
ON z.price = y.max_price
```

Comment: Please specify the RDBMS that you are targeting by adding the appropriate tag (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.). There may be answers that take advantage of language or product features that are not universally supported. Also, by tagging it with a specific RDBMS, your question may receive attention from people better suited to answer it.

Comment: I would like the query to work on both MySQL and SQL-Server, if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to return only those with the `max` total, then you could use the following which works in both MySQL and SQL Server.  It is not any more concise than your current query though:

```
select subscriber
from inventory i
inner join rented r
  on i.dvd = r.dvd
group by subscriber
having sum(replacement_price) = (select max(TotalCost)
                                 from 
                                 (
                                   select sum(replacement_price) TotalCost
                                   from inventory i
                                   inner join rented r
                                     on i.dvd = r.dvd
                                   group by subscriber
                                  ) p);
```

If you are using SQL Server, then I would suggest implementing windowing functions, similar to this:

```
select subscriber
from
(
  select subscriber,
    rank() over(order by sum(replacement_price) desc) rnk
  from inventory i
  inner join rented r
    on i.dvd = r.dvd
  group by subscriber
) src
where rnk = 1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/df620/16)

Comment: Thanks. I've been called in to work early, but I'll check out your code as soon as I can.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough response. I have only been hacking around with SQL for a few days, and only with the MySQL 5.5 pre-installed on my MBP; seeing alternate solutions to problems I've solved helps a lot--especially when they're written by people who actually know what they're doing. Your MySQL query may not be more concise, but it's more readable than mine, and the SQL Server query is very clean. Thanks also for Fiddle link--I hadn't yet gotten around to finding a scratchpad like that to allow me to play with different RDBMSs. I appreciate you taking the time.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT z.subscriber
FROM(
    SELECT RANK() OVER(ORDER BY SUM(replacement_price)) subscriber_rank, 
           r.subscriber subscriber, 
           SUM(replacement_price) totalReplacementPrice
    FROM inventory i
    INNER JOIN rented r ON i.dvd = r.DVD
GROUP BY subscriber
) z
WHERE z.subscriber_rank = 1
```

Some of your column names are different in you query from you sql sample, so I've used the column names given in the demo tables.  I use the rank function in the inner query to find the order of all of the people ordering by the sum of the replacement_price.  Then select the row(s) where the rank is 1.

Rank is available in both MS Sql Server and Oracle.  To go much further than that as @bluefeet says you will need to give more detail as to which database you are targetting.

Comment: I've fixed the column names; sorry about that.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I've unfortunately been called away, so I'll have to try your query later today.

Comment: I'm such a noob I thought you were referring to MySQL as "Oracle" when you wrote "[r]ank is available in both MS SQL Server and Oracle." Took me a minute to realize my mistake when searches for the MySQL RANK() function came up empty. I don't want to limit myself to MySQL, so seeing how it might be done in SQL Server is still quite helpful. I did notice after pasting your query into sqlfiddle (which I didn't know existed until bluefeet mentioned it in his reply) that the ORDER BY clause needs the DESC keyword to get the top, rather than bottom, subscribers.